# Why C# doesn't recognize the Generic

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I think I got lost. I tried to create a method with two generic entries with constraints to them.

The compiler, however, even receiving an instance of the specified generic type, says it is not possible to cast.

[image: Compiler invaliding the Generic Type]

**What is the explanation for this?**

The "expression type" pointed in the compilation error message (*IResponseStreamMessage*) is exactly the *TResponse* constraint *IResponseStreamMessage*. What Am I not seeing? Or aware of?

Just to make sure, this is the **GetResponseStreamOf** method signature:

```
public static IResponseStreamMessage GetResponseStreamOf(IRequestStreamMessage request)
```

**UPDATE**: once I put an explicit cast, it accepts:

```
public static TResponse Get<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, Func<System.IO.Stream> dataProviderFunction)
            where TRequest : IRequestStreamMessage
            where TResponse : IResponseStreamMessage
        {
            return (TResponse) StreamMessagesFactory.GetResponseStreamOf(request);
        }
```

But I still don't get why I have too.

Comment: IResponseStreamMessage can be anything but TResponse, TResponse is IResponseStreamMessage but not other way around. And your cast will fail if your method returns anything other than TResponse.

Comment: Do you need generics for TResponse, or can you just make it that interface?  The problem is that generics permits the caller to specify a derived type of your interface, so there's no guarantee the inner method is returning the exact type.

Comment: It seems the thing goes beyond what I can understand. Only thing I desired was a simple way to Get method callers **not** have to make explicit Casts when the returning instance is for sure known.

Comment: Why does the caller care what the derived type is?  There's no guarantee that the method won't fail with an invalid cast if the implementation of `GetResponseStreamOf` changes.  You should adhere to the Robustness Principle "be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept", which specifying the interface in both cases satisfies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `TResponse` is `IResponseStreamMessage`, `IResponseStreamMessage` is not `TResponse`, say you have a class which implements that interface:

```
class CustomResponse : IResponseStreamMessage
{
}
```

and then you used that class as the stand-in type for the generic `TResponse`. The method sig would look like so:

```
public static CustomResponse Get<TRequest, CustomResponse>(TRequest request, Func<System.IO.Stream> dataProviderFunction);
```

The question is, what type does `StreamMessagesFactory.GetResponseStreamOf` actually return, more than likely not `CustomResponse` so, even tho it returns `IResponseStreamMessage` you won't be able to cast and return it as `CustomResponse`.

You can however check and see if the returned response is of type `TResponse` and if not throw an exception, also, `TRequest` isn't necessary, because what difference does it make if your `request` parameter is `IRequestStreamMessage` or `TRequest`, sins `TRequest` is `IRequestStreamMessage`, so your complete function would be:

```
public static TResponse Get<TResponse>(IRequestStreamMessage request, Func<System.IO.Stream> dataProviderFunction) where TResponse : IResponseStreamMessage
{
    var responseInterface = StreamMessagesFactory.GetResponseStreamOf(request);

    if (responseInterface is TResponse responseObject)
    {
        return responseObject;
    }
    else if (ReferenceEquals(responseInterface, null) && ReferenceEquals(default(TResponse), null))
    {
        return default(TResponse);
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Expected response of type {typeof(TResponse)}, but recieved a response of type {responseInterface?.GetType()}");          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that for your given code generics is not a good choice as it doesn't provide any benefit.

Neither `TRequest` or `TResponse` actually benefit from being generic, if they were replaced with simply `IRequestStreamMessage` and `IResponseStreamMessage` it would behave as expected, with the added benefit of actually compiling.

As for why this is you should consider the body of the `Get<TRequest, TResponse>` method, the only inner method `GetResponseStreamOf` isn't generic.

The only difference with this code with a similar implementation without generics is where the cast (to `TResponse`) will be, within the method or outside of it, which may also be a moot point as I suspect the caller is most likely just fine with the interface as well.

Comment: As I pointed in a comment over there, the Generic-thing came out when I wanted to have a ready-cast way to access any kind of TResponse, being that more than just the Interface description. But I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there are two possible responses:

```
class ResponseA : IResponseStreamMessage
{
}
class ResponseB : IResponseStreamMessage
{
}
```

And `GetResponseStreamOf` returns `ResponseA` (which is legal, the way it is defined):

```
static public IResponseStreamMessage GetResponseStreamOf(IRequestStreamMessage request)
{
    return new ResponseA();
}
```

And someone calls `Get` like this (which, again, is legal):

```
var response = MyClass.Get<IRequestStreamMessage, ResponseB>( ... );
```

The caller says it wants a `ResponseB` back. But your code will return `ResponseA`. While they both implement `IResponseStreamMessage`, `ResponseA` does not inherit from `ResponseB` or vice versa. So this will cause a run-time cast error. The compiler complains because it has no way to know this won't happen.

If you're absolutely sure it won't happen, you have to tell the compiler. That is the reason for requiring an explicit cast.